# LINQ Remove all Users where UserId is in the list

Tags: c#, linq

```
 public JsonResult SearchUser(string term_, int[] assetOwnerIdList_)
    {
        term_ = term_.Trim();

        var userMatches = (from user in _db.Query<User>()
                           where user.Name.Contains(term_) || user.Email.Contains(term_)
                           select new ItemLabelId { Label = user.Email, Id = user.UserId }).ToList().Any();

        return Json(userMatches, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

So here is my code, I want to filter the result, if the user UserId is in the `assetOwnerIdList_` list then remove them  eg `Result.RemoveAll.Where(user.UserId in assetOwnerIdList_)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple:

```
Result.RemoveAll(x => assetOwnerIdList_.Contains(x.UserId));
```

If you want to filter useMatches directly in your query, then:

**This will only work if you query provider supports the contains method (IN Translation), otherwise, use the method above.**

```
var userMatches = (from user in _db.Query<User>()
                    where user.Name.Contains(term_) || user.Email.Contains(term_)
                    && assetOwnerIdList_.Contains(user.UserId) == false
                    select new ItemLabelId { Label = user.Email, Id = user.UserId }).ToList().Any();
```

Comment: Thanks,

Is there any way to include that in the query above so that I can filter the result immediately?

Comment: @simpleProgrammer I was already writing an edit containing that, check it out.

Answer (score 3):

No need to check whether user id is in list or not just use a filter like this:

```
var UserIdList = assetOwnerIdList_.ToList();

var list = userMatches .Where(x => !UserIdList.Contains(x.UserId));

return list;
```

Comment: This works only for one UserId, not for a list of UserIds. But provided `AssetUserId` is already a list (if not, convert it with  `.ToList()` beforehand), you can use: `!AssetUserIdList.Any(x.UserId)` inside of the `.Where(...)` clause.

Comment: if you want to use it with multiple user Ids then first create list of user Ids and then write lamda query using contains it will work.. still you have question let me know

Comment: List<int> UserIdList= new List(GetUserIdList());
lists.Where(x => UserIdList.Contains(x.UserId));

Comment: .Contains and .Any are equivalent. But in each case, you forgot to negate: The question was to return what is **not** in the list. The `!` operator does that.

Comment: can you use like ... lists.Where(x => !UserIdList.Contains(x.UserId));

Comment: Exactly!  `              `

Comment: Sure, I'll do that after you've done the updates discussed.

Comment: Almost ... just replace the list in the first line by `var UserIdList = assetOwnerIdList_.ToList();` and it'll be fine. Regard the parameters [simpleProgrammer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3405068/simpleprogrammer) has provided.